# Mosquitto bridge with websockets

Tags: websocket, mqtt, bridge, mosquitto

I have been using a Mosquitto Broker for a while and I'm able to bridge two brokers by using the bridge functionally in Mosquitto.

My question is, is it possible to bridge two brokers where I need to connect from Mosquitto to the other broker by using Websockets? 
It seems that Mosquitto tries to connect to the other end of the bridge by using only regular MQTT TCP/IP connection and I can't find an option in the CONFIG file to allow for Websockets in the bridge configuration.

I'm getting a "Socket Error" because the other end only supports Websockets.

Comment: Why are you trying to bridge over websockets, what benefit do you see?

Comment: The other broker supports only websockets for it's TLS endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, bridging only works when using native MQTT over TCP not Websockets

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, websockets with mosquitto is only supported for incoming connections.